# How to use dplyr to calculate a weighted mean of two grouped variables

Tags: r, dplyr, weighted-average, summarize, split-apply-combine

I know this must be super easy, but I'm having trouble finding the right dplyr commands to do this.  Let's say I want to group a dataset by two variables, and then summarize the count for each row.  For this we simply have:

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl, mpg) %>% summarize(Count = n())
```

This will generate a dataframe with 27 rows for the three variables `cyl`, `mpg`, and `Count`.  What I'd like to do next is summarize the average `mpg` for each of the three `cyl` values.  Keep in mind that each row may contain a `Count` greater than one which must be considered when calculating the average.  My data frame should have 3 rows of 2 variables `cyl`, and `Avg_mpg`.  Can someone give me the short code chuck that will do this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9):

If I have understood you correctly, you need `weighted.mean`

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
   group_by(cyl, mpg) %>% 
   summarize(Count = n()) %>%
   group_by(cyl) %>%
   summarise(avg_mpg = weighted.mean(mpg, Count))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
#    cyl   avg_mpg
#  <dbl>   <dbl>
#1  4.00    26.7
#2  6.00    19.7
#3  8.00    15.1
```

---

which is equivalent to

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl, mpg) %>% 
  summarize(Count = n()) %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(avg_mpg = sum(mpg * Count)/sum(Count))
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed.  Thank you.

Comment: I think you need to use `mutate(Count = n())`, not `summarize(Count = n())`, so as the weighting column `Count` is added to all rows before calculating the weighted mean. Otherwise the result is exactly the same as the mean grouped by `cyl` only.

Comment: @neilfws I think I agree with you however, the first part of code is provided by OP and I am not sure how are they using it in their real data. So I would leave it to OP to decide how to use it. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 2):

You are effectively performing a simple mean because the weights are the grouping variable:

```
library(dplyr)
options(pillar.sigfig=10) # To check they are identical results
    
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(avg_mpg = mean(mpg))
```

**Output:**

The result is identical to the ones proposed above:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
    cyl     avg_mpg
  <dbl>       <dbl>
1     4 26.66363636
2     6 19.74285714
3     8 15.1
```

If you need a weighted mean based on another variable:

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(avg_mpg = weighted.mean(mpg, disp))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
    cyl     avg_mpg
  <dbl>       <dbl>
1     4 25.81985300
2     6 19.77197631
3     8 14.86285148
```